# How to use llvm::IRBuilder Create Add/Sub/Mul/Div?

Tags: c++, llvm, llvm-clang

I'm trying to use llvm::IRBuilder Create Add/Sub/Mul/Div operations. But there're many apis in https://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1IRBuilder.html#a4ef70bab263e38c5e0b8c1bf95a5d814:

```
Value *     CreateAdd (Value *LHS, Value *RHS, const Twine &Name="", bool HasNUW=false, bool HasNSW=false);
Value *     CreateNSWAdd (Value *LHS, Value *RHS, const Twine &Name="");
Value *     CreateNUWAdd (Value *LHS, Value *RHS, const Twine &Name="");
Value *     CreateSub (Value *LHS, Value *RHS, const Twine &Name="", bool HasNUW=false, bool HasNSW=false);
Value *     CreateNSWSub (Value *LHS, Value *RHS, const Twine &Name="");
Value *     CreateNUWSub (Value *LHS, Value *RHS, const Twine &Name="");
Value *     CreateMul (Value *LHS, Value *RHS, const Twine &Name="", bool HasNUW=false, bool HasNSW=false);
Value *     CreateNSWMul (Value *LHS, Value *RHS, const Twine &Name="");
Value *     CreateNUWMul (Value *LHS, Value *RHS, const Twine &Name="");
Value *     CreateUDiv (Value *LHS, Value *RHS, const Twine &Name="", bool isExact=false);
Value *     CreateExactUDiv (Value *LHS, Value *RHS, const Twine &Name="");
Value *     CreateSDiv (Value *LHS, Value *RHS, const Twine &Name="", bool isExact=false);
Value *     CreateExactSDiv (Value *LHS, Value *RHS, const Twine &Name="");
```

Which one should I use when I want to generate Add/Sub/Mul/Div operations?

Answer (score 3):

`NSW (No Signed Wrap)` and `NUS(No Unsigned Wrap)`

Signed integer overflow occurs when the result of the operation would fall outside the representable range for the signed integer type. For say and Add operation, use `CreateAdd` if you want the result of the operation to wrap around the MAX_INT (i.e $(2)^(32)$ - 1 for unsigned i32) for that integer type in case it exceeds that max value.

By wrapping around we mean if its value exceeds MAX_INT(overflow) then it is set to MIN_INT. `CreateNSWAdd` will allow wrapping for unsigned integers but generate a poison value (undefined behaviour) for signed integers. `CreateNUSAdd` will generate an addition operation allowing wrapping for signed integers but not for their unsigned mates.

Comment: would you please give some examples to explain?

Answer (score -1):

[image: Screen]

```
using System;
namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {

        public static int Addition(int value1, int value2)
        {
            return value1 + value2;
        }
        public static int Subtraction(int value1, int value2)
        {
            return value1 - value2;
        }
        public static int Multiplication(int value1, int value2)
        {
            return value1 * value2;
        }
        public static double Division(double value1, double value2)
        {
            return value1 / value2;
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            while (true)
            {
                Console.Write("\nEnter Value 1 : ");
                int a = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                Console.Write("Enter Value 2 : ");
                int b = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

                Console.WriteLine("Please Enter action to be performed :");
                Console.WriteLine("1. Addition");
                Console.WriteLine("2. Subtraction");
                Console.WriteLine("3. Multiplication");
                Console.WriteLine("4. Division");

                int action = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                string _operation = "";
                double result = 0;
                switch (action)
                {
                    case 1:
                        {
                            result = Addition(a, b);
                            _operation = "+";
                            break;
                        }
                    case 2:
                        {
                            result = Subtraction(a, b);
                            _operation = "-";
                            break;
                        }
                    case 3:
                        {
                            result = Multiplication(a, b);
                            _operation = "*";
                            break;
                        }
                    case 4:
                        {
                            result = Division(a, b);
                            _operation = "/";
                            break;
                        }
                }
                Console.WriteLine("Result A {0} B = {1}", _operation, result);

                char theKey = Console.ReadKey().KeyChar;

                if (theKey == 'y' || theKey == 'Y')
                {
                    Console.Clear();
                    continue;
                }
                else
                {
                    break;
                }
            }


        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: The text in your image is very difficult to read. You should post the output example as properly formatted text, instead.